# How to Create Function Object with attributes in one step

Tags: javascript, function, object

This is an academic question, to clarify my understanding of JavaScript.

A function object can be assigned attributes once it is created. However, is it possible to create a function object with attributes in one step?

For example,

```
function someFunction(){
}

var someFunctionObject=someFunction;


someFunctionObject.attr1="attr 1";

alert(someFunctionObject.attr1); /* "attr 1"
```

Here the attribute is being added in the second step, after the object has been created. Is it possible to achieve this in one step?

Comment: No, but you can omit the `someFunctionObject=someFunction` assignment and just do `someFunction.attr1=...`.

Comment: Or you can do `var someFunctionObject = function() {}`

Comment: It's seems you have to clarify what is the actually result you want to get. If you just want to assign a property to a function, then no, there is no way to combine this in one step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is no. Read below for the explanation.

The end result of your code is something like:

```
var myFunctionObject = {
    prop1: 'foo',
    prop2: 'bar',
    construct: "alert('function body')"
};
myFunctionObject(); // should alert
myFunctionObject.prop1; // 'foo'
```

A function definition/declaration actually does something very similar - it creates an object with the [[Construct]] property set to the actualy body of the function. But, this is just an implementation detail and you cannot access or set that [[Construct]] property separately, so you cannot define other properties in one-go (it would require additional syntax and there is none available).

But, you can set properties from inside the function, if that's what you need. For example, this would be useful for caching:

```
function getSomething() {
    if (getSomething.prop) return getSomething.prop;
    return getSomething.prop = fetchResource();
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work that way. The constructor property is supposed to be a function and not a string. Try it.

Comment: Yes, I know it's a function, but I thought it would only make the explanation more confusing if I wrote another function in there. I will update my response if I get any more feedback.

Comment: @AaditMShah - actually I'm not sure you understood what I was refering to in my response. I was talking about this [[Construct]]: http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-13.2.2

Comment: You said it yourself: you can't directly modify the internal [[Construct]] property. However, you can use closures and named functions to solve the problem. No need for constructors.

Comment: Felix and Draevor understood my question. Thanks to both. I will accept this as the correct answer. 

Reading the various responses I have also learned a bit more about JavaScript itself. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to do so is to assign a named function to a variable as follows:

```
var someFunctionObject = (function someFunction() {
    if (!someFunction.attr1) {
        someFunction.attr1 = "attr1";
        return someFunction;
    }
    // extra processing
}());

alert(someFunctionObject.attr1);
```

This has the added advantage that if someone deletes the attr1 property, it'll be reinitialized later as follows:

```
delete someFunctionObject.attr1; // deleted
someFunctionObject();            // reinitialized
alert(someFunctionObject.attr1); // back to square one
```

A better way to write the above construct would be:

```
var someFunctionObject = (function someFunction() {
    if (someFunction.attr1) {
        // extra processing
    } else {
        someFunction.attr1 = "attr1";
        return someFunction;
    }
}());
```

This is both faster and better because:

1. We don't use the logical NOT operator. This saves an instruction to execute when interpreted. Logical NOT doesn't coerce, so using it has no benefits.
2. The function object is usually only initialized once, so logically the initialization should come last as it'll be rarely called.

Comment: +1 Overly complex, but possible, be aware that IE 8 has weird issues with named functions that looks like they would be effected by this solution... http://kangax.github.com/nfe/

Comment: One can argue whether this is still one step. I can always create a function, put every assignment inside and call it to make it one step. It does not even have to be that difficult, you could for example take jQuery's `$.extend` function.

Comment: It isn't one step, but at least it's one expression. That's probably as close as you can get.

Comment: Using this method has several other advantages. It can be used to reset the state of the function if the attr1 property is deleted. This is possible because the named function is a closure which closes over itself (weird construct - but it works in JavaScript). Wow, this is really high level stuff! I should probably write a tutorial to explain it in more detail. Oh, and you can create reference variables to the function object by deleting attr1 and assigning the function call to another (reference) variable. Pointless, but interesting to study in theory.

Answer (score 0):

```
function someFunction(attr1){
  this.attr1 = attr1; 
}

var someFunctionObject = new someFunction('attr 1');
console.log( someFunctionObject.attr1 );
```

Comment: That's not the same as the OP's code. `someFunctionObject` is not a function.

Comment: @Felix ... yes it is... unless you're for some reason making a distinction between the object and it's reference...

Comment: @jondavidjohn: Uhm... I'm pretty sure it is not.`new someFunction('attr 1')` returns an empty object which inherits from `someFunction`'s prototype. But you can see for yourself if you type `typeof someFunctionObject`. It does not return `function`. *Edit:* Clarified, was a misunderstanding :)

Comment: @jondavidjohn: No, it is not.

Comment: @Felix ahhh... misunderstanding, you mentioned the OP's code and then made a statement about the **answer's** code... thought you were still discussing the OP's code... my bad

Comment: @jondavidjohn: Ah ok... sorry :)

Answer (score 0):

```
var someFunc = new function(attr1){
  this.attr1 = attr1; 
}("blah");

alert(someFunc.attr1);
```

That's one step, but not a very useful construct.

Comment: Same here: `someFunc` is not a function. The OP wants to assign the property to the function (as far as I understood it).

Comment: Can you explain how this is different? The result is a function object either way, correct? And the code does work.

Comment: No. `someFunc` is an *object* inheriting form the constructor functions prototype. It is not a function, you cannot call it. The OP is assigning the property directly to the function, not to an object returned by a constructor function.

Comment: Ahhhhh, I see. I created an anonymous constructor function, not a function object.

Answer (score -1):

You're only a tiny (but important) bit off in your phrasing. What you did in your sample code was make a function, then assign that function as a property on another object (`someFunctionObject`).

What you did in literal terms looks like this:

```
var someFunctionObject = {
    someFunction : function(){},
    attr1 : "attr 1"
}
```

This results in one `object` (`someFunctionObject`, which is poorly named at this point, as it's just a regular object) with two properties assigned to it: one string, and one function.

Comment: Actually `someFunctionObject` is not a property, it's just another variable. The assignment seems to be superfluous

Comment: In that case ("...make a function, then assign that function as a property on another object...") I meant what I said. Objects have properties, but you could also call them name/value pairs or anything else you choose. Sorry if this was ambiguous?

Comment: Actually I'm not sure what the OP really wants. But your code is not the same as the OP's. You are creating an object with two properties, a function and a string, whereas in the OP's code, the function itself as the property.

Comment: The OP's code translates as: var someFunctionObject = function someFunction() {}; someFunctionObject.attr1 = "attr 1";